# When I load a php file into a div to get results in if/else as echo, it does not work

Tags: php, json

I have a php file to validate email.

```
<?php
// include pdo config
include_once ('config.php');

// store the values submitted by form in variable
session_start();
$email=$_POST['i_email'];

// query
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='$email'") as $row); {
    if ($email == $row['Email']) {
          $valid = "<script>
        $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
          </script>";
    } else {
          $valid = "<script>
        $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
          </script>";
      $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
    }
    echo $valid;
}

$pdo = null;
?>
```

Now I use an ajax code to load it into a div.

```
function i_check_email(id) {

    var val_i_email = $("#input_email").val();
    var i_session = <? $_SESSION['valid'] ?>
    $('#a_loader_i').show();

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/script/validate_email.php',
    data: {i_emial:val_i_email},
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
    if (i_session) {
        $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
    }
    }
    });
}
```

The ajax code works fine. The php has somewhat problems though. It does not act upon the if/else. Is there any possible way around this and validate the email? And how to use json to validate it?

Comment: if u alert `i_session` in success function. you will get idea. check whether response is getting correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand well you want to check the email's uniqueness in the database. if it's true it's enough to verify the count of the rows and sending back 1 if valid or 0 if not and using those values in the js code

the validator:

```
<?php
// include pdo config
include_once ('config.php');

// store the values submitted by form in variable
session_start();
$email=$_POST['i_email'];

// query
$rs = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE email='$email'");
echo ($rs->fetchColumn(0) > 0 ? '0':'1');

$pdo = null;
?>
```

and in js:

```
function i_check_email(id) {
var val_i_email = $("#input_email").val();
$('#a_loader_i').show();

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: '/script/validate_email.php',
data: {i_emial:val_i_email},
cache: false,
success: function( answer ) {
    if (answer == '1') {
        $('#input_email').addClass('valid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('invalid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#input_email').addClass('invalid');
        $('#input_email').removeClass('valid');
        $('#a_loader_i').hide();
    }
}
});
}
```

ps: the trickiest part of your code was the semicolon right after the closing bracket of the foreach ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX code you send `i_emial` but in the PHP you look for `i_email`. So it's presumably never going to find a matching email in the database.